# Установка FreePBX на asterisk 13.1 или как перенести все настройки на новый сервер?

Tags: asterisk, centos6, freepbx

Есть asterisk 13.1 на centOS 6.6 кем и когда было настроено хз, сервер начал работать иногда с сбоями ( в основном ругается на диски ). Помогите разобраться как перенести конфигурацию на 14 версию. С нуля настроить не выходит нигде не могу найти как было связано с дсл ватсон. Или как настроить входящие номера через модем?
Или как можно перенести центос на виртуалку?

Comment: Прямо берёте и через dd образ целого диска уносите. Там его конвертируете из raw в qcow и привязываете к виртуальной машине.

Comment: Пытались восстанавливать из образа, не получилось. Астер не запускался. Проще конфиги скопировать из /etc/asterisk/* и собрать астериск. Конфиги от 13 на 14 без проблем подойдут